Errors running builder 'CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection)
Am using Eclipse with JBoss Tools to develop JSF 2.3 & JPA 2.2 based web application for Apache TomEE 8.0.16 server with Hibernate as JPA implementation. My project has many drop down menus and would like to use Hibernate second level cache to improve application performance. Hibernate specific @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE) annotation added to entity and all other hibernate properties in presistance.xml. But, during project builds, JBoss Tools CDI builder failing to build project and content assist not available in JSF views. If this @Cache annotation removed, total project builds without error and content assist is available in JSF views, i.e., JSF beans, bean instance variable objects and bean methods.
Project Configuration:

Java - 1.8
Dynamic Web Module 4.0
CDI (context dependency Injection) - 2.0 with bean-discovery-mode="all"
JPA - 2.2
JavaServer Faces  - 2.3
JBoss Tools - 4.29.1, Eclipse 2024-06
Apache TomEE 8.0.16 with Hibernate 5.6 as JPA implementation

Entity
@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class User implements Serializable {

  @Id
  private String id;

  private String fname;
  
  private String lname;

  -------- constructor, getters  & setters ----
  
 }

Eclipse build error
 Errors occurred during the build.
 Errors running builder 'CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection) Builder' on project 'demo'.
 'java.lang.Object org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo()'

Project is compiling with above error, but Eclipse content assist not available in JSF views (.xhtml files)
How to remove this CDI build error

@శ్రీ have you managed to solve your problem with the CDI builder? I get the same error (not using Hibernate Cache) with Eclipse 2024-06 and latest JBoss Tools

@Vasil Svetoslavov Not solved, getting same error.

I think i fixed it by removing JBoss Tools entirely (except for the app server adapter). Started a fresh eclipse installation, fresh workspace, freshly checked out projects and it seems it did the trick... Good luck with your case! :)

yes, still getting same error.

Referring to Quarkus' Hibernate guide/chapter "Caching", I can see two things:

The entity itself needs to be annotated with @Cacheable, not @Cache
You have to make sure that the Quarkus property quarkus.hibernate-orm.second-level-caching-enabled in application.properties is set to true; this is the default value anyway

The @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.xxx) annotation seems to take effect on entity collections/relations only (see here).
